# How to access to Business Objects in Stimulsoft Report Code Behind

Tags: c#, stimulsoft

I'm new to stimulsoft report desinger. As you know, it's available to write C# code in report.

I want to create a function to filter my Business objects and return a value. but the question is **How can I access business objects in code behind the report?**

Unfortunately I found nothing about documentation!

Answer (score 1):

The correct way is to connect a report object to the data source and then you can add [filters](https://www.stimulsoft.com/en/documentation/online/user-manual/report_internals_creating_lists_data_filterting.htm?zoom_highlightsub=filter).

To access the data programmatically you can use this.Dictionary...

Answer (score 0):

you can handle bussiness object of stimulsoft in c# with beloow code -

StiReport report = new StiReport();
 List lst= new List();

```
        if (lst.Count() > 0)
        {
            report.Load(Server.MapPath("~/ your path/ReporFile.mrt"));
            report.RegData("YourDataObjectInReport", lst);
            report.RegBusinessObject("YourBussineessObject",lst);
        }
        else
        {
            report = NoDataReport();
        }
        return StiMvcViewer.GetReportSnapshotResult(report);
```